# Get e-mail Contacts from exchange 2007 in C#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

Is anybody know how to pull contact list from Microsoft Exchange 2007 using c#?

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good 3 part tutorial on the CodeProject with regards to programming with Exchange Server 2007 in C#. See [Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/exchange/Exchange2007EWS-Part1.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link, and I forgot to mention that I’m using windows app, not a web app. So when i add web service as Service Reference it's seems to be different than Web Reference.

Comment: I figure it out, you actually can add web reference into win app. you just need to click advanced options when you adding service reference.

Comment: Yeah sorry never realised you left a comment on here! Yes I had a similar issue a while back trying to use web services with a console application! Glad you sorted it.